# Database for efficient large-scale graph traversal

Tags: mongodb, networking, graph, database

I have a large bipartite directed graph dataset (~20 million elements). In its current use, I run traversal algorithms that hit ~500,000 nodes per run. The algorithms work, but historically run off of data loaded to memory from text files.

Text files seem like a bad approach, so I transferred the data into mongoDB as an adjacency list, ie.

```
{ _id: 1, children: [2, 3] }
{ _id: 2, children: [4] }
{ _id: 3, children: [5, 6, 7] }
```

This works, but I feel like the model is inefficient for what I'm doing. In pseudocode, the query structure for a breadth-first search starting from _*id: 1* would look like:

```
children = getChildren(_id = 1)
for child in children
    grandchildren = getChildren(_id = child)
    // etc., either recursively or as a nested loop
```

The issue I have with the database is that there's no logic connecting nodes. Every query has to traverse the index tree, which, if I'm not mistaken, is O(log N). The text file approach is O(1) after loading, as I can make some simple lookup rules to point directly to node children.

**TL;DR** Is there a way to traverse a large network in O(1) time using a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [Neo4J](http://neo4j.org/), a NoSQL graph database. I haven't used it, but it promises high performance.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is not a multi-purpose database. You are clearly interested in using a dedicated *specialized* graph database. Using MongoDB for such graphs and related search algorithms is a no-go.

Comment: Judging from your previous posts, it seems like you **really** dislike mongo. Any reason?

Answer (score 0):

**GraphScope** is a fast, efficient, and highly scalable graph query system, and perhaps it is what you need.
GraphScope is a powerful distributed graph computing platform, and GAIA-IR is the interactive graph query engine in GraphScope.

In fact, GAIA-IR outperforms mongoDB (as well as Neo4j Communication Version) by orders of magnitude. But that's not all - GAIA-IR provides a unified intermediate representation layer, which means that various graph query languages can be easily incorporated. e.g., GAIA-IR already supports the most popular graph query languages of Gremlin and Cypher.

You could refer to this [article](https://blog.graphscope.io/gaia-ir-graph-interactive-query-engine-in-graphscope-340993f4637c) to learn the design of GAIA-IR and how it can be deployed and used.

Disclaimer: I'm an author of GraphScope.