# Neo4j or MongoDB for relative attributes/relations

Tags: database, mongodb, neo4j, graph-databases

I wish to build a database of objects with various types of relations between them.  It will be easier for me to explain by giving an example.

I wish to have a set of objects, each is described by a unique name and a set of attributes (say, height, weight, colour, etc.), but instead of values, these attributes may contain values which are **relative to other objects**. For example, I might have two objects, A and B, where A has height 1 and weight "weight of B + 2", and B has height "height of A + 3" and weight 4.

Some objects may have completely other attributes; for example, object C may represent a box, and objects A and B will be related to C by the relations "I appear x times in C".

Queries may include "what is the height of A/B" or what is the total weight of objects appearing in C with multiplicities.

I am a bit familiar with MongoDB, and fond of its simplicity. I heard of Neo4j, but never tried working with it.  From its description, it sounds more suitable for my need (but I can't tell it is capable of the task).  But is MongoDB, with its simplicity, suitable as well?  Or perhaps a different database engine?

I am not sure it matters, but I plan to use python as the engine which processes the queries and their outputs.

Answer (score 2):

Either can do this.  I tend to prefer neo4j, but either way could work.

In neo4j, you'd create a graph consisting of a node (A) and its "base" (B).  You could then connect them like this:

`(A:Node { weight: "base+2" })-[:base]->(B:Node { weight: 2 })`

Note that modeling in this way would make it possible to change the base relationship to point to another node without changing anything about A.  The downside is that you'd need a mini calculator to expand expressions like "base+2", which is easy but in any case extra work.

Interpreting your question another way, you're in a situation where you'd probably want a trigger.  [Here's an article on neo4j triggers, how graphs handle this](https://maxdemarzi.com/2015/03/25/triggers-in-neo4j/).   If parsing that expression "base+2" at read time isn't what you want, and you want to actually set the value on A to be b.weight + 2, then you want a trigger.   This would let you define some other function to be run when the graph gets updated in a certain way.  In this case, when someone inserts a new `:base` relationship in the graph, you might check the base value (endpoint of the relationship) and add 2 to its weight, and set that new property value on the source of the relationship.

Comment: I didn't know about Neo4j trigger support. Sounds handy!

Comment: Well, triggers are honestly not something neo4j yet supports, but Max's blog is really great, and he can show you how to make it possible with existing server extensions which have been possible for some time.  Up to you to define the scope of what kinds of triggers you want.   But your use case: "calculate X on the basis of some other piece of data" is **the** classic database trigger use case.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use either DBMS.

To help you decide, this is an example of how to support your uses cases in neo4j.

To create your sample data:

```
CREATE
    (a:Foo {id: 'A'}), (b:Foo {id: 'B'}), (c:Box {id: 123}),
    (h1:Height {value: 1}), (w4:Weight {value: 4}),
    (a)-[:HAS_HEIGHT {factor: 1, offset: 0}]->(h1),
    (a)-[:HAS_WEIGHT {factor: 1, offset: 2}]->(w4),
    (b)-[:HAS_WEIGHT {factor: 1, offset: 0}]->(w4),
    (b)-[:HAS_HEIGHT {factor: 1, offset: 3}]->(h1),
    (c)-[:CONTAINS {count: 5}]->(a),
    (c)-[:CONTAINS {count: 2}]->(b);
```

"A" and "B" are represented by `Foo` nodes, and "C" by a `Box` node. Since a given height or weight can be referenced by multiple nodes, this example data model uses shared `Weight` and `Height` nodes. The `HAS_HEIGHT` and `HAS_WEIGHT` relationships have `factor` and `offset` properties to allow adjustment of the height or weight for a particular `Foo` node.

To query "What is the height of A":

```
MATCH (:Foo {id: 'A'})-[ra:HAS_HEIGHT]->(ha:Height)
RETURN ra.factor * ha.value + ra.offset AS height;
```

To query "What is the ratio of the heights of A and B":

```
MATCH
  (:Foo {id: 'A'})-[ra:HAS_HEIGHT]->(ha:Height),
  (:Foo {id: 'B'})-[rb:HAS_HEIGHT]->(hb:Height)
RETURN
  TOFLOAT(ra.factor * ha.value + ra.offset) /
  (rb.factor * hb.value + rb.offset) AS ratio;
```

Note: `TOFLOAT()` is used above to make sure integer division, which would truncate, is never used.

To query "What is the total weight of objects appearing in C":

```
MATCH (:Box {id: 123})-[c:CONTAINS]->()-[rx:HAS_WEIGHT]->(wx:Weight)
RETURN SUM(c.count * (rx.factor * wx.value + rx.offset));
```

Comment: Thank you for a detailed example! I will need to learn it a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used Mongo and decided not to after studying it. So filter my opinion with that in mind; users may find my comments easy to overcome. Mongo is not a true graph database. The user must create and manage the relationships. In Neo4j, relationships are "native" and robust.

There is a head to head comparison at this site:
[https://db-engines.com/en/system/MongoDB%3bNeo4j]

see also: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688745/database-for-efficient-large-scale-graph-traversal](https://neo4j.com/graph-databases-book/)

There is a distinction between NoSQL (e.g., Mongo) and a true graph database. Many seem to assume that if it is not SQL then it's a graph database. This is not true. Most NoSQL data bases do not store relationships. The free [book](https://neo4j.com/graph-databases-book/) describes this in chapter 2.

Personally, I'm sold on Neo4j. It makes relationships, transerving graphs and collecting lists along the path easy and powerful.

Comment: Perhaps the comparison link is broken?